# Mouse wheel click scroll bug in chromium

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, chromium

I find out strange behaviour of Chromium.
We have a page with Iframe and some scrollable content on it.

```
<div id="d1"><div id="d2">Lorem ipsum ***</div></div>

#d1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
#d2 {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kotodid/r40hf1g8/

Iframe is internal part of jsfiddle and I only add scrollable div.

I try to scroll this div mouse wheel click-and-move - and current page hangs. After this I can do nothing on this page: no clicks, no form edit. Only close tab.

Do anyone have such issue? Is this a known bug?

I tried on different PC using Windows 7 and browsers on Chromium: Chome (42.0.2311.135 x32), Opera (29.0.1795.47 x32), Vivaldi (1.0.162.2 x64). Each has such problem. Firefox or IE - does not. Normal scroll with arrows or wheel turning does not cause issue too.

Comment: Wow, this is weird. Never experienced this before. Can be reproduced in my Chrome setup.

Comment: no problem here, i have chromium 44.0.2395.0 64bit

Comment: I use 42.0.2311.135 32bit and have this problem for a loooong time. Hope it will be solved in 44...

Comment: This issue from long time here too, and everywhere, its even in many sites like Facebook, yahoo mail